# Как сделать ссылку и к якорю внутри страницы и чтоб переходило по ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Задача такая, чтобы при клике на ссылку он переходил по ней в новом окне (target="_blank"),  и чтобы на этой же странице на которой ссылка он проскролливался к айди. Возможна ли такая реализация?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного грязное решение, безусловно можно сделать лучше

Пример в playcode: https://playcode.io/681771/

Условный html-контейнер:

```js
var Links = document.querySelectorAll('.go');

Array.from(Links).forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // для новой вкладки используйте код
    // window.open(event.target.dataset.link, '_blank').focus();
    window.open(event.target.dataset.link, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
  });
});
```

```css
#first, #second, #third {
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="first">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<a class="go" data-link="http://yandex.ru" href="#third">to third</a>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
<p>
Diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam. Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum. Aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor. Gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci. Cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque nec nam. Eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris. Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum sagittis. Nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta. Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim.
</p>
<a class="go" data-link="http://lenta.ru" href="#first">to first</a>
  </div>
  <div id="third">
<p>
Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi. Ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla. Id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet. Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl condimentum id. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum eu. Adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate. Faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum. Neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet.
</p>
<a class="go" data-link="http://google.ru" href="#second">to second</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

В этом примере #first, #second, #third - DIV'ы, к которым скроллимся или от которых скроллимся

Сссылки `<a href="#айди" data-link="абсолютный путь" class="go">текст</a>`, где айди - id блока к которому скроллимся

В JS условный лиснер (лиснер можно повесить не на класс, а на [data-link], для примера это не важно), который при клике на ссылку открывает окно с url соответствующим тому, который указан в data-атрибуте data-link

Comment: Работает частично, открывает пустую новую вкладку (about:blank)

Comment: В каком браузере не работает? Я в хроме тестировал, код работал

Comment: Пример https://playcode.io/681771/

Comment: в хроме делаю, что то не так...

Comment: Посмотрите пример в playcode по ссылке выше, в нем работает как нужно?

Comment: открывает в новом окне, а не во вкладке

Comment: а так да всё открывается

Comment: В посте вы указали - открывать в новом окне

Comment: ошибся... нужно в новой вкладке)

Comment: Для открытия в новой вкладке можно использовать вместо прежнего window.open(...) - этот window.open(event.target.dataset.link, '_blank').focus()

Comment: Обновил ответ с учетом открытия ссылки во вкладке. Пример здесь: https://playcode.io/681771/?v=2

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Но опять же с некоторыми оговорками, например если ссылка в таком формате (внутри ссылки что то помимо текста) <a><img></a>, то не работает(открывает пустую вкладку)

Comment: Такие условия, лучше было сразу уточнить. В коде event.target - определяет то, по чему кликнули, в случае последнего вашего комментария - определит изображение <img> и не найдет параметр dataset у изображения, т.к. dataset привязан к <a>. Как вариант - использовать closest, пример https://playcode.io/681771/?v=3

Comment: В этом случае closest вернет ближайший <a> и затем у него найдется нужный dataset.link

Comment: Всё, идеально! Спасибо огромное добрый человек!

Comment: Можете выбрать ответ в качестве решения вопроса, так решение было бы проще найти другим участникам

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a href="blalba/blabla#id" target="_blank"> blabla</a>
```

Comment: Наверное, не поняли, ссылка не относительная, а абсолютная. Нужно чтобы условно говоря при клике открылась новая вкладка с условным гуглом, а на изначальной страничке он проскролился к id

Comment: в этом случае остается цеплять в data-id, и через скрипт делать прокрутку, в событии клик

Comment: А как это сделать? Сорян я вообще профан в js